# I'm attempting to change an image's source (and therefore display) when a right arrow is clicked. However, the image becomes "undefined"

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
//images used. 

var imageData = "https://i.vimeocdn.com/video/246976999_640.jpg"
var imageData1 = "aHR0cDovL2Z1bnRpbWVzbmV3cy5jb20vd3AtY29udGVudC91cGxvYWRzLzIwMTUvMDcvU2VhLUJ1bm5pZXMtQXJlLUxhdGVzdC1DcmF6ZS1Jbi1KYXBhbi1Gb3ItQXF1YXJpdW0tVGFua3MtMS5qcGc=";
var imageData2 = "http://celebratewomantoday.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/03/Chirpy-Duckling-sitting-on-box-3.jpg";
var imageData3 = "http://www.name-list.net/img/portrait/Hamster_3.jpg";
var imageData4 = "http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-4FGnh3WIdTE/Th7-yF2W8QI/AAAAAAAAARM/2ZR1zx6WWe4/s1600/Puffer+Fish.jpg";

//array containing the images so that they can be iterated

var allImages = [imageData, imageData1, imageData2, imageData3, imageData4];
var count = 1;

$("#right").click(function() {
  if (count < 5){
  document.getElementById("hello").src = allImages[count];
  count++;
  }
});

var image = new Image();


var can = document.createElement('CANVAS');
var ctx = can.getContext('2d');

can.height = 63;
can.width = 80;

previewDataURL = document.getElementById("hello").src;

image.onload = function() {
    ctx.drawImage(this, 0, 0, 80, 63);
    //new cropped image's base64 
    document.getElementById("normalPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("vintagePic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("lomoPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("clarityPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("sinCityPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("sunrisePic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("crossProcessPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("orangePeelPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("lovePic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("grungyPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("jarquesPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("pinholePic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("oldBootPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("glowingSunPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("hazyDaysPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("herMajestyPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("nostalgiaPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("hemingwayPic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
    document.getElementById("concentratePic").src = can.toDataURL("image/jpeg", 0.5);
};
image.src = document.getElementById("hello").src ;
```

So what I'm trying to accomplish here is that when the user clicks the right button, the next photo in the array is displayed.

I've added `console.log(document.getElementById("hello").src)` before in the right click function to see if the source of "hello" was changing and it was. I've also added the `console.log(document.getElementById("hello").src)` after the `image.onload` function and I receive "undefined". What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: codepen - http://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/qNoYwr  one of the image URL is wrong ,that is getting blank

Comment: imageData1 - aHR0cDovL2Z1bnRpbWVzbmV3cy5jb20vd3AtY29udGVudC91cGxvYWRzLzIwMTUvMDcvU2VhLUJ1bm5pZXMtQXJlLUxhdGVzdC1DcmF6ZS1Jbi1KYXBhbi1Gb3ItQXF1YXJpdW0tVGFua3MtMS5qcGc=

Comment: `imageData1` isnt a valid [data uri](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs), it needs to start with something like `data:image/png;base64,`

Answer (score 2):

This image is a base64 image, For using it you should add a data type:

```
var imageData1 = "data:image/jpeg;base64,aHR0cDovL2Z1bnRpbWVzbmV3cy5jb20vd3AtY29udGVudC91cGxvYWRzLzIwMTUvMDcvU2VhLUJ1bm5pZXMtQXJlLUxhdGVzdC1DcmF6ZS1Jbi1KYXBhbi1Gb3ItQXF1YXJpdW0tVGFua3MtMS5qcGc=";
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_URI_scheme

Answer (score 0):

It looks like count is initialised to 1, that's the second element in your array. That particular element does not have a proper address `("aHR0cDovL2Z1bnRpbWVzbmV3cy5jb20vd3AtY29udGVudC91cGxvYWRzLzIwMTUvMDcvU2VhLUJ1bm5pZXMtQXJlLUxhdGVzdC1DcmF6ZS1Jbi1KYXBhbi1Gb3ItQXF1YXJpdW0tVGFua3MtMS5qcGc=")`

Comment: Thanks, I changed the URL. Still doesn't work though :(